# Weighted arithmetic mean's alternative for ranking items

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, ranking, weighted-mean

I have a Blog post ranking algorithm which has 5 factors which are considered for calculating final score.

I have predefined input range according to which i decide score of a factor.

e.g.
Factor : Post_Title_length
ideal length = 40 characters

[0,-10],[20,50],[40,100],[80,50],[100,25],[150,0],[1000,-20]
now if the input is 35 it's associated y coordinate on a Line formed by points (20,50) and (40,100) would give score of this factor.

After doing this for each factor final score is calculated as
$\frac{\sum{X_i*W_i}}{\sum{W_i}}$ where W is weight of a Factor.

I would like to know what alternatives are available to this approach and what are the drawbacks of this approach and how machine learning can be used here.